# How to fix 'window.layer.getSource(...).getFeatures() is not a function'

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to use the api getFeatures() to get the features.But it tell me getFeatures() is not a function.Where do I need to solve it?

```
componentDidMount(){

window.a = [];

window.layer = new Tile({

  source: new TileArcGISRest({  

    url:'http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyMapService/MapServer',

    })
});
for(let i=0;i<83;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<87;j++){
    for(let k=0;k<5;k++){
      for(let l=0;l<5;l++){
        window.a.push([98.875+0.025*j+0.005*k,26.7-0.025*i-0.005*l,rain.data.values[i][j]])
        //a.push([100.875+0.025*j+0.0025*k,26.7-0.025*i-0.0025*l,rain.data.values[i][j]])
      }
    }
  }
}
 var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    window.layer
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [100.1811924164254, 25.78602688913871],
    projection: 'EPSG:4326', //设定坐标系
  })
});

let features = window.layer.getSource().getFeatures();
for (let j = 0; j < features.length; j++){
  var polygonGeometry = features[j].getGeometry();
  window.b = window.a.filter(item=>polygonGeometry.intersectsCoordinate([item[0],item[1]]))
  }
}
```

I just want to judge whether a point is in a certain area.And to use intersectsCoordinate(), I have to get the feature.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example to reproduce the error?

Comment: TileArcGISRest is a raster source, only vector sources have features

Comment: for EsriJSON vector features from ArcGIS take a look at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html